# Why does inline IF assignment requires else statement?

Tags: python

```
x = 'foo' if x == 'bar' else x
```

now this would be equal to :

```
x = 'foo' if x == 'bar'
```

but this returns "invalid syntax" error. Is there a reason why this works like it does or what's the reason behind the design decision? Because it's how multi-line if function is (functions like example #2):

```
if x == 'foo':
    x = 'bar'
```

and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because it's not a statement but an expression.  It must evaluate to something, so you can't exclude the else condition.  Also, since it's an expression, you can't (really, you shouldn't) do anything that would mutate state.

More info here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Of course, something like this is entirely possible:

```
class C(object):
    def foo(self):
        self.y = 1
        return 'foo'

c = C()

c.foo() if True else 'bar'

print c.y

# Prints '1'
```

...so mutating state in a ternary expression is actually not prohibited; it's just not recommended.

Comment: wouldn't it make sense if it defaulted to itself if no else statement found though? or implementing something like that to the programming language is not worth it or would break logic/design?

Comment: What does "defaulted to itself" mean? In your example, `x` might not already be defined, or it might not even be getting assigned to a variable - `print(1 if x else 2)` is valid code.

Comment: @Bernard: defaulted to *what* exactly? There is no 'itself'; the expression is not aware of what the outcome will be used for. `'foo' if x == 'bar' else x` is *just an expression*, not connected to any assignment statement or anything else you'd use it for.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing this with something like Ruby's `<statement> if <condition>` syntax.  I would imagine that Python lacks this kind of syntax because of its design philosophy -- that there should be one (and preferably only one) obvious way to do things.

Answer (score 10):

To the Python interpreter, this line of code...

```
x = 'foo' if x == 'bar' else x
```

**isn't** interpreted like this...

```
(x = 'foo') if x == 'bar' else (x = x)
```

but rather is interpreted like this:

```
x = ('foo' if x == 'bar' else x)
```

This is because the ternary `x if cond else y` operator in Python is an *expression* rather than a statement - it can be used anywhere you'd specify a value.

Thus, you can also use it, for example, in cases where you're not doing assignment:

```
print("hi" if x == 'bar' else "bye")
```

Because it's an expression, it always needs to be able to resolve to some value, so that the value can be used in whatever context the expression is being used.

Answer (score 3):

The python mantra says there should be only one way to do things. We already have:

```
if x == 'foo': x = 'bar'
```

Why would we want:

```
x = 'bar' if x == 'foo'
```

Comment: Regardless of whether this is true, it's not the actual answer to the question.

Comment: That is very true, however doesn't the first statement go against PEP8 of "no multiple statements on one line"? My Pycharm keep swearing at me whenever I do this.

Comment: @Amber: "what's the reason behind the design decision?" - I think quoting `import this` counts here

Comment: Correct, PEP views this poorly. But that's a style decision, not a language decision

Comment: @Eric I'm okay with quoting `import this`, but I'm not okay with omitting the actual technical reason *in favor of* quoting `import this`. The expression/statement difference is the more critical fact.